# Add to a v-date-picker, a personalized drop-down list (v-select) vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to know if it is possible to add to a component date / month pickers(v-date-picker), a personalized drop-down list (v-select) for the month and the year as in the example give? Thank you

Comment: Would you please show what you have tried

Comment: which example do you refer to?